# Attempting a discrete proof: Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

So this is an exercise that is a supplement to my studies in discrete math, I want to understand what my error is. The online training drill I
 am using reports the below is incorrect / or as we would say in discrete math illogical. Thank in advance.

Please note: 
The online tool we are using has the below lines and I have to rearrange them in the correct order.  The lines below are how I decided to arrange them.

$$
Theorem:  \forall m,k \in \mathbb{Z}, m~even ~\land~ k~even ~\rightarrow~ 4 \mid (k  m)
$$

$$
ab \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

$$
k,m \in \mathbb{Z} ~\land~ k~even ~\land~ m ~even
$$

$$
∃a ∣ k = 2a ∧ ∃b ∣ m = 2b
$$

$$
km = (2a)(2b)
$$

$$
km = 4(ab)
$$

$$
4 ∣ km
$$

$$
\therefore \forall m,k \in \mathbb{Z}, m~even ~\land~ k~even ~\rightarrow~ 4 \mid (k  m)
$$

Comment: The fourth line should read: $\exists a, b\in \Bbb Z\; (k=2a \wedge m=2b)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp The online tool we are using has the above lines I posted and I have to rearrange them in the correct order. Is there a way to derive your observation by reordering the lines I posted?

Comment: @user1787331 You need to put that information in the question so users will know precisely what your question is.

Comment: Do you have a link to your online training tool or is access restricted?

Comment: The line $ab\in\Bbb Z$ should go immediately before the line $4\mid km$; otherwise it’s correct (albeit in my opinion a perfectly awful drill). It’s the fact that $ab$ is an integer that lets you deduce $4\mid km$ from $km=4(ab)$.

Comment: It is access restricted. We are using webwork. http://webwork.maa.org/

Answer (score 2):

What you have is almost correct. The one line that is out of place is $ab\in\Bbb Z$: it belongs after $km=4(ab)$ and before $4\mid km$, because it’s the fact that $ab$ is an integer that lets you conclude from $km=4(ab)$ that $4$ divides $km$.

**Added:** Here’s how the proof might read if it were written up in normal fashion instead of in this skeletal form.

> Let $k$ and $m$ be even integers. Then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $k=2a$ and $m=2b$. Clearly $km=(2a)(2b)=4(ab)$. Moreover, $ab$ is an integer, so by definition $4\mid km$.

Comment: Somehow I misread it as $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. I'd agree with you that this is a "perfectly awful drill". If everything is laid out as OP has it, then I'm surprised $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\ldots$ isn't included.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you for your help. A question: so it seems that $$ ∃a ∣ k = 2a ∧ ∃b ∣ m = 2b  $$ is where the a and b are first introduced?

Comment: @user1787331: Yes, it is. Give me a few minutes, and I’ll add a properly written version of the proof to my answer; the schematic used in that exercise is pretty poor.

Comment: @user1787331 Yes, that is actually the reason behind my comment on Brian's post. They should have $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ before the statement you just mentioned. The $a$ and $b$ come out of nowhere. They use $ab\in\mathbb{Z}$ due to closure of multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$. As Brian said though, the schematic used in your exercise is pretty poor. Shame on the MAA!

Comment: Its not the MAA, they make the tool, the person who wrote the drill does not work for the MAA.

Comment: @user1787331 Well then...shame on *that* person then. Seems like you should just accept Brian's answer and move on.

Comment: @crash: I’ve used WeBWorK. It’s not bad for routine calculus drills, for instance, if the person writing the problem code does a decent job. It’s perfectly adequate for this drill, too, despite the composer’s failure to specify that $a$ and $b$ are integers; my problem is with the drill itself. Outside proof theory, automated theorem proving, and the like, a proof is a piece of expository prose, written in (paragraphs of) sentences, with appropriate notation as needed. Students should be pointed in this direction from the start and **not** encouraged to think of proofs as jigsaw puzzles.

Comment: I agree. This exercise seems to be poor on many fronts IMO. Regardless, glad the OP got things settled and you provided a good / more appropriate answer. (+1)

Comment: The above is not the teachers fault, the class was falling behind our schedule and we were struggling with like proofs in a more open format. So to get a better sense of where we are at the open format was restricted to the format I posted.